# Can't I use a component defined in a file other than app.component.ts in HTML directly?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am facing difficulty in using a component  defined in a file named navigation.component.ts directly on HTML Page. 
The same component works fine if I use it under template of a component defined on app.component.ts.

Contents of app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NavigationComponent} from './shared/navigation.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, NavigationComponent],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Contents of navigation.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
     selector: 'navigation',
     templateUrl: '/views/shared/navigation.html'
 })

 export class NavigationComponent {
     userName: string = 'Anonymous';
 }
```

Contents of app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
     selector: 'main-app',
     template: '<navigation></navigation><h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>'
 })

 export class AppComponent {
     pageTitle: string = 'Portal 2.0';
 }
```

Contents of index.html

```
  <body>
        <main-app></main-app>
  </body>
```

The above works and renders menus on top but when I try to use `<navigation>` directly (given below) it doesn't render it, doesn't show any errors either.

```
  <body>
        <navigation></navigation>
  </body>
```

**Am I doing something wrong?**

**And the bigger question is how I go debugging issues like this?**

Comment: you set the app to bootstrap into the `AppComponent`, which is looking for a `main-app` element that isn't existent in your second example. You could bootstrap into `NavigationComponent`, which will find the `navigation` element.  The element that you bootstrap is the `root` element, all other angular elements are children of this element. the name `app` is usually used for the `root` by convention, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Claies are you referring to following line that I have in index.html     <script>
        System.import('app').catch( function (err) {console.error(err);});
    </script>

Comment: no, I am referring to your `@NgModule` declaration, where you `bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]`.  either way, since you can't bootstrap into the `body` tag, putting `<navigation></navigation>` in the body element doesn't make a lot of sense, unless you want everything in the app to be a child of the navigation element......

Comment: @Claies I see what you are referring to, so in a way the structure of the app should have one root element holding all children? The root element becomes owner. I guess I need to read more about bootstraping, happy to accept your comment as an answer if you can drop that as an answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use web components. Add all the components that you want to load to entrycomponents.
Using createCustomElement  you can create elements and use their selector anywhere.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    console.log('Elements is loaded: Activation');
    this.registerComponent('metro-activation-loader', AppComponent);
  }

  public ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    console.log('Elements is loaded: Activation ngDoBootstrap');
   }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  private registerComponent(name: string, component: any): void {
    const injector = this.injector;
    const customElement = createCustomElement(component, { injector });
    customElements.define(name, customElement);
  }
}
```